# Why won't this delete query work (ERROR 1093 (HY000))?

Tags: mysql

*This is the query as I should try so far:*

```
   DELETE 
     FROM food_detail 
     WHERE food_id 
     IN 
     (
     SELECT DISTINCT food_id FROM food_detail 
     );
```

I think logically there shouldn't be a problem since the select query will give me a list of IDs which i will delete based on.

This is the error i got :

```
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'food_detail' for update in FROM clause
```

Comment: Aren't you just deleting everything from the table? Why do you need the subquery?

Comment: Truncate doesn't work on my table. So this is the best method

Comment: But why do you need the subquery? Why not just `delete from food_detail`?

Comment: How will i do that ? with a single query ?

Comment: `DELETE FROM food_detail` will empty the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do?

Your query will remove all non-null `food_id` in the table.

I suspect that you want to remove all `food_id` that only appear once.  If so, use `delete` with a `join`:

```
DELETE fd
    FROM food_detail fd JOIN
         (select food_id
          from food_detail fd
          group by food_id
          having count(*) = 1
         ) fd1
         on fd.food_id = fd1.food_id;
```

You can also use the same approach for your original query:

```
DELETE fd
    FROM food_detail fd JOIN
         (select distinct food_id
          from food_detail fd1
         )
         on fd.food_id = fd1.food_id;
```

But that seems like a cumbersome way of saying:

```
DELETE food_detail
    WHERE food_id is not null;
```

Comment: Why do you repeat `COUNT(*)` in your HAVING clause when you already gave it an alias in the `SELECT` clause? It should be `HAVING cnt = 1`.

Comment: @Barmar . . . Because I can't always remember which databases allow aliases in the `having` clause and which do not.

Comment: OK, then I'll ask it the other way: why did you put `COUNT(*) AS cnt` in the `SELECT` clause if you're not using it?

Comment: @Barmar . . . The honest reason is because when I start writing the query, I know the filtering on `count(*)` is needed.  I don't know if I'm going to put it in the `having` clause or in the `on` clause -- the two are equivalent functionally.

Answer (score 2):

You have to warp the sub-query inside another query, like this:

```
DELETE FROM food_detail 
WHERE food_id IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT food_id FROM food_detail
  ) AS t
);
```

Mysql does not allow you to reference the same table inside an inner query.